# Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, domdocument

I need to create a function that returns html based on an url.

```
function start()
{
        $url = "http://dostuff.com";

        $site = new \DOMDocument();
        $site->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

        //do stuff with it
        $listview = $site->getElementById('colLeft');
        var_dump($this->getValuesOfAttribute($listview,'a','href'));
}
```

This actually works, however I need to use this functionality in several other functions.So I might aswell fetch the content in its own method.

```
    public function start()
    { 
        $site = $this->getHTMLByURL("http://dostuff.com");

        //do stuff with it
        $listview = $site->getElementById('colLeft');
        var_dump($this->getValuesOfAttribute($listview,'a','href'));
    }

    public function getHTMLByURL($url)
    {
        $site = new \DOMDocument();
        return $site->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    }
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementById() on a
>   non-object in
>   [file_path]
>   Call to a member function getElementById() on a non-object

Why is '$site' a non-object? doesn't it have the same value it had on the first function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function `getHTMLByUrl` isnt returning what you think it is.

```
public function getHTMLByURL($url)
{
    $site = new \DOMDocument();
    return $site->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));   
}
```

its returning the boolean result of the `loadHTML` call, not the object.

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) for the documentation.

what you need to do is:

```
public function getHTMLByURL($url)
{
    $site = new \DOMDocument();
    $site->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    return $site;    
}
```

Comment: So it was returning the boolean from the LoadHTML and instead of DOMDocument. Thank you.